# automatically update \addbibresource file path

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, winedt

Is there a way to automatically update the file path of where my references are stored?  I keep them in a folder "References".  This is the full path to my references:

```
\addbibresource{C:/Users/bossman/Desktop/Document/References/chap1.bib}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/bossman/Desktop/Document/References/chap2.bib}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/bossman/Desktop/Document/References/chap3.bib}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/bossman/Desktop/Document/References/chap4.bib}
```

The main folder "Document" is where all my tex and other related files are stored.  If I move the Document folder now to let's say F:/LatexFiles, or even another computer, my \addbibresource complains and I have to go and update the path now manually. Is it possible to automate this filepath name?

Here is a screen shot of my folder structure. The References folder is where my .bib files are in:

[image]

and here is the References folder with my chap.bib files:

[image]

Comment: With TeX Live (even on Windows?) you have the `BIBINPUTS` variable, to which you could add your "personal" locations.  But I don't really know Windows, and I really don't know MiKTeX (if you are using that)....

Comment: I am using MiKTeX and Windows 7.

Comment: What about relative paths? That is `\addbibresource{./References/chap4.bib}` and the like.

Comment: I get the error Cannot find './References/chap4.bib'!

Comment: Relative pathes as suggested by moewe should work if your bib-files are really in a subfolder of your tex document and if you are starting biber from the folder of the tex document.

Comment: LaTeX or `biblatex` cannot keep track of your files - they cannot hunt them down if the went missing. Maybe there is some kind of editor that has some project feature allowing for this. The best you can do with LaTeX is relative paths, so if your `.tex` files are currently in `Document`, then specify the paths to the bib file as `./References/chap2.bib`.

Comment: I have just included a screen shot of my folder structure.  Book.tex is the main file where I run my LaTeX compiler.  I still get the error in BibTeX `Cannot find './References/chap1.bib'!`.

Comment: I just checked this with a similar set-up on my machine with bot Biber and BibTeX and both worked fine. Would you be able to set-up a very small MWE for us and tell us exactly what messages you get from Biber/BibTeX?

Comment: Ohhhhh, I just remembered. If you store your aux files in a different folder via some option in the command line or in some editor, LaTeX might actually (think it is) be(ing) executed in that folder thus changing the needed relative path, try `../References/chap2.bib` note the double `.`.

Comment: @moewe, you solution with the `..` worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@moewe gave the solution where the path had to include double periods...i.e., the path would now be

> addbibresource{../References/chap1.bib}

.

Answer (score 7):

### UPDATE

In WinEdt 9.1 build 20150713 the bug described below has been solved.

Simply use

```
\addbibresource{References/chap1.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap2.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap3.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap4.bib}
```

and biber will compile your bibliographies correctly.

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

The correct way is to use

```
\addbibresource{References/chap1.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap2.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap3.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap4.bib}
```

But you are using WinEdt 9 and there is a bug in the compiler script for BibTeX and biber which prevents biber to run successfully when you redirect your auxiliary files to another folder.

To circumvent this (it will be fixed in the next release of WinEdt), open the file `BibTeX.edt` (it should be somewhere like `C:\Program Files\WinEdt 9\Exec\TeX`), then open the Options Interface and click on "Advanced Configuration".

Now click on the button "Create and Open Local Copy". A modifiable local copy of `BibTeX.edt` gets opened.

[image]

Just after the line

```
  IfIStr("%$('%!9-Executable');","bibtex.exe","<>",!"LetReg(3);");
```

insert the lines

```
  IfIStr("%$('%!9-Executable');","biber.exe","=",>
    !|IfStr('%O','%P','<>',!`LetReg(3,'--input-directory "%P"');`);|);
```

Now save the file and the job is done.

Try recompiling your file and now WinEdt correctly runs biber on your bibliographies.