# WinEdt warning message for .bib files

Tags: biblatex, winedt

In the screen capture below:

[image]

Why is there a warning in the WinEdt tree structure that the bib files cannot be found.

My document compiles normally as I have the following commands for my biblatex:

```
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../References/chap1.bib}
\addbibresource{../References/chap2.bib}
\addbibresource{../References/chap3.bib}
\addbibresource{../References/appendix.bib}
```

This is an image for my folder structure:

[image]

I am able to compile my document correctly, but just curious as to why I get this warning from WinEdt in the tree structure?

Comment: I assume we are talking about [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249291/35864) situation? In that case then, I think WinEdit's tree structure component thinks that the working directory is the one you showed in the screenshots, let's call it `doc` (for lack of information on its real name), obviously then `doc/../References/chap1.bib` is an invalid path, and the correct path is `doc/References/chap1.bib` (so no `..` there, maybe just a `.`). But in your situation LaTeX's working directory is TeXAux making `../References/chap1.bib` the correct relative path from TeX's point of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WinEdt assumes that the paths of the files which have to be collected in its Tree interface are relative to the main document being processed.

So, you have to use

```
\addbibresource{References/chap1.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap2.bib}
\addbibresource{References/chap3.bib}
\addbibresource{References/appendix.bib}
```

instead of

```
\addbibresource{../References/chap1.bib}
\addbibresource{../References/chap2.bib}
\addbibresource{../References/chap3.bib}
\addbibresource{../References/appendix.bib}
```

To circumvent the errors when compiling your bibliographies with biber, see [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254602/27635).