# No Citations visible in LyX 2.3.0

Tags: lyx, citing, jabref

I have a document which has an associated .bib file that is created using Jabref. I include the ful; path to the .bib file in the Latex preamble using the commands:

```
\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource {C:/Users/tkpme/Dropbox/Book PCRM/mpsbookNew.bib}

\renewcommand\cite{\citet}
```

In the past, I have had no difficulty choosing an item when I wanted to insert a citation. All of a sudden, no citations at all are available to choose from when I click on Insert > Citation! Oddly enough, citations I inserted in the past get processed correctly when I generate a pdf - I just can't insert any new citations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thomas Philips

Comment: Where is your main file? (Full path)

Comment: My main file is in C:/Users/tkpme/Dropbox/Book PCRM/Chapter 18

Comment: Try `../mpsbookNew.bib` instead. This means to go back to the parent directory (the "..") and look there for the file. See here (the accepted answer): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249291/automatically-update-addbibresource-file-path

Comment: I tried it, and I'm afraid this doesn't work. I had tried this earlier, and found that relative paths didn't work, so I then switched to an absolute path and it worked perfectly for a while. I tried to edit the file again today and couldn't see any available citations in the pop-up window. I'll read your accepted answer and see if there are any hints in there that might be relevant.

Comment: The answer is not mine there... It is not even belong to its author. The problem is that I can not help because I don't use lyx. Please consider accepting one or more answers on your previous questions to have more possibilities to get help and to offer this way to the community too. I hope someone can help you. The only think I can think, is that may be removing the space from the main folder name would do the trick. But can not test it.

Comment: Figured it out! At the end of the document I had an TeX box which said BibTeX Generated Bibliography. Once I clicked on that I had to add a new local database, and I added the database in the root directory. Once I did that everything was fine. In summary, I had to fix things in two places - one in the LaTeX Preamble and the second in the Bibtex Generated Bibliography

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! At the end of the document I had an TeX box which said BibTeX Generated Bibliography. Once I clicked on that I realized that I had to add a new local database, and I added the database that is sitting in the root directory. Once I did that everything was fine. In summary, I had to fix things in two places - once with the path in the LaTeX Preamble and the second time with the database in the Bibtex Generated Bibliography

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when my .bib file was in the same folder as my .lyx file. In the "BibTeX Generated Bibliography" dialog I just had to add a "./" in front of the .bib file name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My setup was: Master document (e.g. thesis.lyx) with included child document, where the Bibtex Generated Bibliography resided (e.g. references.lyx). The references were not visible in the Lyx:Citation dialog in the master document nor in other child documents (chapters).
Turned out, setting "Select default master document" in the settings of "references.lyx" to "thesis.lyx" made the difference.